# 'Video undefined' using youtube API with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have used the iframe youtube api to work with the video . It works well on chrome and fx, but when it is implemented on IE 8 , it return error of 'video' is undefined. How to fix the problem ? thanks

```
        function loadAPI(){
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        }

// add youtube movie 
$(target).append("<iframe class = '" + className + "' id = '" + id + "' src  = '" + src + "?wmode=transparent' ></iframe>");

function bindYouTube() {
    var player;
    player = new YT.Player(currYoutubeID, {
      videoId: currYoutubeLink,
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange (event) {
    if (event.data == 0)                     
        $("#" + event.target.a.id).remove();
}
```

p.s. I believe the code i am using is not the root of problem since it works as expected on chrome and fx. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some browsers, a Flash embed (Flash is used by the iframe embed on non-HTML5 platforms) won't initialize if the element is hidden.  It's been that way for a long time unfortunately.  Positioning the embed off screen is a good way to get around it. To start debugging this, make sure your element is visible.